# Getting "NoMethodError" via ajax call with strong params but it works fine without it

Tags: ajax, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use strong parameters via ajax call and I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'permit' for ...)` with the codes below:

ajax call

```
onSubmit(value) {
  const url = '/tweets/create';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      tweet: value
    },
    success: (data) => {
      // whatever
    },
    error: (xhr, status, err) => {
      console.error(url, status, err.toString());
    },
  });
}
```

tweets_controller.rb

```
def create
  tweet = Tweet.new(create_params)
  tweet.save
end

private
  def create_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:tweet)
  end
```

tweet.rb

```
  belongs_to :user

  validates :tweet, { presence: true }
```

However, it works fine if I don't use strong parameters with the same ajax call like below:

```
def create
  tweet = Tweet.new(tweet: params[:tweet])
  tweet.save
end
```

How can I make it to work with strong parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the problem is that the argument for the permit function should be one or more (or an array) of scalar values, and not an object? According the the [Git Hub documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters),

> To whitelist an entire hash of parameters, the permit! method can be used
>
> `params.require(:log_entry).permit!`

You could try

`params.require(:tweet).permit!`

if you haven't already, and see if that fixes it. Otherwise, there is lots of documentation on the link above which might help. If you are still stuck, try posting the code from your tweets.rb file above as well so others can test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tried `params.require(:tweet).permit!` yet it didn't change the situation...

Comment: Can you post your tweets.rb file as well?

Comment: It looks to me like your Tweet class has one attribute, which is also called a tweet. Is that correct? It's hard for me to recreate the error you are getting on my system, but I suspect the trouble might be coming from the fact that your tweet object and its attribute are referred to the same way. To rule that out, you could change the name of your attribute to message (although that might blow up the rest of your code) and then try `params.require(:tweet).permit(:message)` If that doesn't work, I am out of ideas. Best of luck with this.

Comment: Although, you can't just change the name of the attribute without migrating your database I don't think. So maybe that wouldn't be an easy thing to try. Hopefully an expert will chime in soon and get you going.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply & thank you so much for your effort in trying to help. My problem still hasn't been solved but I appreciate your comment.